# how to sort a list without build-in function

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, sorting

I want to sort a list like below.Without using the build-in function so I tried this:

```
    sort[n_] := 
     Module[{n0 = n, i, j}, 
      Do[Do[If[n[[j - 1]] > 
           n[[j]], {n[[j - 1]], n[[j]]} = {n[[j]], n[[j - 1]]}],
         {j, Length[n], i, -1}];
       , {i, 1, Length[n] - 1}]; n]
l = {2, 1, 1, 10, 9, 8, 1};sort[l]
```

But it seem my code is not correct.Can Anyone help me to figure out this. Any hints or solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you using `Sort`? Is this homework? Also you should use a semicolon `;` instead of a comma `,` before calling `sort`.

Comment: There are more than a dozen methods of sorting (BubbleSort, QuickSort, MergeSort, HeapSort, InsertionSort, IntroSort, SelectionSort, ...).

Comment: I really need to do it using for/while/Do.it's a problems which was given a contest.So i am excited to solve @user6014 Sir :)

Comment: Look up 'HoldFirst'.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is - nearly - ok. But you return `n`instead of `n0` and you should work on a temporary variable (`n0`or here  `temp`). It is always a good idea to use variable names that are (a bit) self explanatory. So make something like:

```
  sort[list_] := 
     Module[{temp = list, i, j}, 
      Do[Do[If[temp[[j - 1]] > 
           temp[[j]], {temp[[j - 1]], temp[[j]]} = {temp[[j]], temp[[j - 1]]}],
         {j, Length[temp], i, -1}];
       , {i, 1, Length[temp] - 1}]; temp]
```

I have changed only variable names, for me more easy to read. But.... Bubblesort is one of the worst you can take.

**Edit**
I forgot to mention, that you can implement Bubblesort in a rule-based approach in a oneliner (it is O(n^3), but nice)

```
bubbleRule[xs___, x_, y_, ys___] := bubbleRule[xs, y, x, ys] /; x > y
```

Then `bubbleRule @ list` sorts list ;-)

Comment: Yes.finally got it.Thanks @mgamer Sir for your advice.

Comment: @mgamer Very tricky!!! I tried to test it  `bubbleRule[{1, 5, 2, 4, 3}]` but MMA doesn't  sort...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: By definition `bubbleRule` has not a list as argument, so you should use ist like: `bubbleRule @@ list` but you can define: `bubbleRule[{xs___, x_, y_, ys___}] :=  bubbleRule[{xs, y, x, ys}] /; x > y`

Comment: @mgamer Thanks!